# The Kernel of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-transformations

I came across this question which involves using information about the image and kernel of a linear transformation in order to work out the actual equation for the linear transformation, it's as follows:

Write down a linear transformation S: $\mathbb R^4$ --> $\mathbb R^3$ of rank 2 and nullity 2. Write down the matrix for S with respect to the standard bases for $\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^3$ as well as an explicit formula for $$S\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
t
\end{pmatrix}$$

After looking at the answer for the question that was given, I agree that the part in the formula that is missing should be $\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ however I am unsure as to what this means for the kernel. If the solutions to the transformed matrix are x=0 and y=0, how does this give a null of 2? Surely the null has no dimension as it is just the zero vector?

Comment: You are looking for elements of the domain (in $\Bbb R^4$) that map to $0$. For example $x=y=z=0$, $t=1$ would (presumably; I assume that last vector you wrote represents the range).

Comment: It follows from the rank nullity theorem. The range is $2$-dimensional, so that the kernel has dimension $4-2=2$.